# Spring Mvc method argumrnts

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I new in Spring MVC. When I change the following code :

```
@RequestMapping("/showform")
public String showForm(Model theModel) {

    Student student = new Student();

    theModel.addAttribute("student", student);

    return "student-form";
}
```

to this following code:

```
    @RequestMapping("/showform")
public String showForm() {

    Model theModel;

    Student student = new Student();

    theModel.addAttribute("student", student);

    return "student-form";
}
```

I get this Error: **The local variable theModel may not have been initialized**.

My question is how come `Model theModel` is initialized in the first place (as method argument)??

Comment: Whatever (the Spring MVC infrastructure) called the `showForm` method initialized and passed in the `Model` argument.

Comment: Spring is magic, it injects dependencies from parameters depending on the annotation you are using. So the first one works because of spring giving the value to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basic Java and has nothing to do with Spring. Local variables and method parameters are initialized differently.

For a method parameter the initialization is implicit because you must give some value to the method call. Example:

```
// Declaration
public String showForm(Model theModel) {
}

// Call
showForm(null);
```

You cannot ommit the argument and so the method parameter is initialized with the value that you pass to the method call.

For a local variable it is different. If you just declare it without any value assignment the variable is not initialized. The following code would compile:

```
public String showForm() {
  // Note the initialization with null!
  Model theModel = null;
  Student student = new Student();
  theModel.addAttribute("student", student);
  return "student-form";
}
```

Anyway, that would cause a NPE at runtime of course.

Comment: Does Spring MVC call showForm and sends value for theModel (I mean is showForm is called inside Spring MVC)? I got it, behind the scenes it's Java that really initialize theModel. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Yes, Spring does some magic when calling controller methods (those annotated with @RequestMapping). It looks at the method declaration via Reflection API and if it finds a method parameter of type `Model` then Spring MVC will pass a Model instance for this parameter. That happens behind the scenes. You can simply rely on that in your controller methods.